# How do i pass the arguments with self

Tags: python-2.7

```
def read_contents(self,filename):
    with open(filename,'r') as f:
        lines=f.read().splitlines()
        print lines

s=read_contents('input.txt')
```

When trying to run this program the error is thrown as two arguments required and self needs to be present as one of the arguments (this is part of a bigger code)
how do i pass filename as arguments without getting error

Answer (score 1):

You must use it within a class:

```
class Test:
    def read_contents(self, filename):
        with open(filename, 'r') as f:
            lines = f.read().splitlines()
            print lines

test = Test()
s = test.read_contents('input.txt')
```

Or remove the self:

```
def read_contents(filename):
    with open(filename, 'r') as f:
        lines = f.read().splitlines()
        print lines

s = read_contents('input.txt')
```